# Same issue just started

Tags: thermal-runaway

Thermal runaway e1 ender 3 nozzle temp steady till it moves then nozzle temp drops and jumps all over then I get the thermal runaway. Also When wiring up to computer, it registers its there but it's unrecognized and won't communicate with it. I'm stuck. I don't have the money to throw at it and not sure how to check each part.

Comment: Sounds like something is shorting on the thermister.  Can you open the print head and look for bare wires or loose wires ?

Comment: It looks like you are asking two separate questions. One is possibly answered in the duplicate question proposed by Criggie, the other one needs more information to help find a solution.

Comment: The title should be changed to ask a single simple question.